# how refill a column with the help of 2 other column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data based 3 groups : SAMPN,PERNO,loop

there are 2 columns, mode1 and mode2. and a column called int.

```
   SAMPN     PERNO    loop    mode1    mode2    int
    1         1         1        1       2       NA
    1         1         1        2       1       NA
    1         1         1        3       2        0
    1         2         1        3       2        NA
    1         2         1        1       1        2
    2         2         1        3       2        NA
    2         2         1        1       3        NA
    2         2         1        3       1        0
    2         2         2        1       2        NA
    2         2         2        3       1        2
```

`SAMPN` is family index, PERNO is index of persons in each family and loop is tour of each person. the last row of each loop for each person is 0 or 2 and and rest of loop is NA. in each family and for each person and each loop I want copy the column mode 1 in int if the last row of loop is 0 and copy mode2 if the last row of loo is 2.

output

```
   SAMPN     PERNO    loop    mode1    mode2    int
    1         1         1        1       2       1
    1         1         1        2       1       2
    1         1         1        3       2       3
    1         2         1        3       2        2
    1         2         1        1       1        1
    2         2         1        3       2        3
    2         2         1        1       3        1
    2         2         1        3       1        3
    2         2         2        1       2        2
    2         2         2        3       1        1
```

the first 3 rows is loop of first person in the first family, I filled that loop by mode1 because the third row was 0. and so on

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using *dplyr*

```r
df <- read.table(h=T,text="SAMPN     PERNO    loop    mode1    mode2    int
1         1         1        1       2       NA
1         1         1        2       1       NA
1         1         1        3       2        0
1         2         1        3       2        NA
1         2         1        1       1        2
2         2         1        3       2        NA
2         2         1        1       3        NA
2         2         1        3       1        0
2         2         2        1       2        NA
2         2         2        3       1        2")

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(loop, SAMPN, PERNO) %>%
  mutate(int = if(last(int) == 0) mode1 else mode2) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    SAMPN PERNO  loop mode1 mode2   int
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1     1     1     1     2     1
#>  2     1     1     1     2     1     2
#>  3     1     1     1     3     2     3
#>  4     1     2     1     3     2     2
#>  5     1     2     1     1     1     1
#>  6     2     2     1     3     2     3
#>  7     2     2     1     1     3     1
#>  8     2     2     1     3     1     3
#>  9     2     2     2     1     2     2
#> 10     2     2     2     3     1     1
```

If you have more values than `0` or `2`, switch could be a good alternative :

```
df %>%
  group_by(loop, SAMPN, PERNO) %>%
  mutate(int = switch(
    as.character(last(int)),
    `0` = mode1,
    `2` = mode2)) %>%
  ungroup()
# same output!
```

Comment: sorry I misread (several times) your question :). Now should be good hopefully

Comment: Error in if (last(mode.car.overlap) == 0) mode else mode2 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: This error is triggered when `NA` is fed to `if`. It means that you have a subgroup of distinct values of SAMPN, PERNO and loop for which the last value of int is NA

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(loop, SAMPN, PERNO) %>%
   mutate(int = case_when(rep(last(int) == 0, n()) ~ mode1, TRUE ~mode2))
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   loop, SAMPN, PERNO [4]
#   SAMPN PERNO  loop mode1 mode2   int
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1     2     1
# 2     1     1     1     2     1     2
# 3     1     1     1     3     2     3
# 4     1     2     1     3     2     2
# 5     1     2     1     1     1     1
# 6     2     2     1     3     2     3
# 7     2     2     1     1     3     1
# 8     2     2     1     3     1     3
#9     2     2     2     1     2     2
#10     2     2     2     3     1     1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(SAMPN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), PERNO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), loop = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), mode1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), mode2 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), int = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 2L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```